# Zend Mail and encodings, content-transfer etc. - Unified?

Tags: email, zend-framework, encoding

Is there any class in the Zend Framework that allows me to **easily** read emails?

The Zend_Mail class does allow me to easy get headers, subject and the content body. But transferring everything to UTF-8 and human-readable format is still a pain.

Or am I doing something wrong? As far as I can tell, Zend Framework does not allow me to easily get UTF-8 strings that I can just use, I still have to do some post-processing. Right?

Comment: early in 2010 i did some experiment with zend mail pop3 classes and it was really easy , i was able to real the mail content ,subject and  form , i was testing only in english  , could you please give an example about encoding issue ....

Comment: As soon as you have different Content-Transfer-Encodings or sent emails with umlauts in subject, from or any other header you will run into problems... There is a lot of stuff like this:  =?ISO-8859-1?B?SmV0enQgZ/xuc3RpZyBpbiBkaWUgVVNBIGZsaWVnZW4gLSBt?=
 =?ISO-8859-1?B?aXQgTWVpbGVuIG9kZXIgYWIgNDQ5IEV1cm8q?=
and as far as I can tell, the Zend Framework does not automatically take care of this.

Comment: this seems to be base64_encoded string , this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834152/why-doesnt-this-mail-message-decode-correctly

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.encoding.html

Comment: I used imap_mime_header_decode to convert it and then iconv to convert it to UTF-8. But shouldn't the Zend Framework do this automatically when I get the Header values from Zend_Mail_Part? This is such a pain...

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is that you need to iterate over the parts within the Message and find the text. Once you have it, then you can use `quoted_printable_decode` to get the text itself in a useful way.

This is some rough and ready code that reads IMAP email boxes with Zend_Mail:

```
<?php
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array(
        'host'   => EMAIL_ACCOUNT_HOST,
        'user'     => EMAIL_ACCOUNT_USERNAME,
        'password' => EMAIL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD,
    ));

echo (int)$mail->countMessages() . " messages found\n";

foreach ($mail as $message) { 

    $from = $message->getHeader('from');
    $subject = trim($message->subject);
    $to = trim($message->to);
    $body = getBody($message);

    // do something with message here
}

function getBody(Zend_Mail_Message $message)
{
    // find body
    $part = $message;
    $isText = true;
    while ($part->isMultipart()) {
        $foundPart = false;
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($message);
        foreach ($iterator as $part) {
            // this detection code is a bit rough and ready!
            if (!$foundPart) {
                if (strtok($part->contentType, ';') == 'text/html') {
                    $foundPart = $part;
                    $isText = false;
                    break;
                } else if (strtok($part->contentType, ';') == 'text/plain') {
                    $foundPart = $part;
                    $isText = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if($foundPart) {
            $part = $foundPart;
            break;
        }
    }
    $body = quoted_printable_decode($part->getContent());

}
```