# Email decoding doesn't work in zend mail

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-mail

I have a script that access the specified email and fetches mail. `$temp->getContent()` echos the following..

```
----boundary_2710_edfb8b44-71c8-49ff-a8cb-88c83382c4ee 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
boundary=--boundary_2709_dde0dd0e-ba35-4469-949d-5392aec65750 --boundary_2709_dde0dd0e-ba35-4469-949d-5392aec65750 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
PGZvcm0gbWV0aG9k.........this part is base64 encoded and it works fine if i copy and decode it separately.......AgICAgICAgICAgDQoNCjwvZm9ybT4= 
----boundary_2709_dde0dd0e-ba35-4469-949d-5392aec65750-- ----boundary_2710_edfb8b44-71c8-49ff-a8cb-88c83382c4ee 
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=--boundary_2711_eca4cfc3-fc62-43d6-b9fb-e5295abbfbe8 ----boundary_2711_eca4cfc3-fc62-43d6-b9fb-e5295abbfbe8 Content-Type: application/pdf; 
name=redBusTicket.pdf 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment Content-ID: JVBERi0xLjIgCiXi48/TIAoxIDAgb2JqIAo8PCAKL1R5cGUgL0NhdGFsb2cgCi9QYWdlcyAy IDAgUiAKL1BhZ2VNb2RlIC9Vc2VOb25lIAovVmlld2VyUHJlZ
```

Between this content there is base64 encoded part and it works fine if i copy and decode it separately. Also there is a attachment in the mail. How can i get the attached file. The following is my code. when i use the base64_decode directly i get no output.. just a blank page..

```
$storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($imap);
$temp = $storage->getMessage($_GET['mailid']);
echo base64_decode($temp->getContent());
```

the documentation in zend website is not very good. Need some help!!

Comment: Can you provide the complete and unedited original version of the message that you are trying unsuccessfully to parse?  It sounds like it's not a well-formed MIME message, but you should get an Exception if that was the case.

Comment: Does this tend to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834152/why-doesnt-this-mail-message-decode-correctly

Comment: @Charles its kinda confidential information so i can't share the encoded part.. When its been decoded i get a html output which i see exactly at my gmail.

Comment: @Sudhir that's not the one am looking for.. i found out the problem anyway.. i have to get the mail parts individually using getPart()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have something like this to get the base_64 contents from an email. Try to filter out what you dont need.

```
if ($email->isMultipart() && $partsCount){

    for($i = 1; $i < $email->countParts() +1; $i++) {
        $part = $email->getPart($i);
        $headers = $part->getHeaders();
        if (
            array_key_exists('content-description', $headers)
             || array_key_exists('content-disposition', $headers)

        ){
            if (array_key_exists('content-description', $headers)) {
                $att = $part->getContent();
                $filepath = utf8_encode(DATA_PATH . '/' . $part->getHeader('content-description'));
                if (is_file($filepath)) {
                    unlink($filepath); // deletes previous files with same name
                }
                $file = fopen($filepath, "w");
                fwrite($file, base64_decode($att));
                fclose($file);
                $attachments[] = $filepath;
            } 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i used getPath directly to do the job.. but in some cases its not base64 its quoted printable encoding.. i am unable to find the "content transfer encoding" type to use base64 decode or quoted printable decode.. please suggest....

Comment: I dont understand you. You have Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 in your headers. I've edited the headers for you.

Comment: i didn't see the edit.. But getHeaders function is not returning Content-Transfer-Encoding.. I guess i'll have to getPart first and getHeaders.. Ill check and let you know..

Answer (score 4):

It works good for me:

```
foreach ($mail as $message) {

    $content = null;      
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($message) as $part) {
        if (strtok($part->contentType, ';') == 'text/plain') {
            $content = $part;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($content) {
        echo "\n encode: " . $content->contentTransferEncoding;        
        echo "\n date: " . $message->date;
        echo "\n subject: \n" . iconv_mime_decode($message->subject, 0, 'UTF-8');
        echo "\n plain text part: \n" . mb_convert_encoding(base64_decode($content), 'UTF-8', 'KOI8-R');
    }

}
```