# How to read accents using Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap

Tags: zend-framework, email, smtp

I'm trying to read mails with Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap. Here is a part of my code :

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(
        array(  'host' =>'imap.gmail.com',
                'ssl' =>true,
                'port'=>993,
                'folder'=>'inbox',
                'user' => '***',
                'password' => '***' 
            )
        );


    foreach ($mail as $k => $message) {
             $msg = $mail->getMessage( $k );
             echo $msg->getContent();
    }
```

Everthing work's well, except the accent format. I have things like this :

int=C3=A9gration for intégration

S=C3=A0rl*  for sàrl

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
utf8_decode( quoted_printable_decode( $part->getContent() ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into the "getText()" method here:
http://wiip.fr/content/zend-mail-storage-imap

The text is in french, but don't bother and only take what you need into this getText method. Basically you need to determine the encoding of the email & decode it.

You can also have a look there : [Email decoding doesn't work in zend mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938668/email-decoding-doesnt-work-in-zend-mail)

Comment: I have tried to use your class. It make me an Exception. $contentTransfertEncoding is empty...

Comment: What about the 2nd solution? THe 1st one may be outdated (it's 3 years old...)

Answer (score 0):

here it is a possible solution if you use utf-8 internal encoding.

```
/**
 * retrieves message content
 * @param Zend_Mail_Message|Zend_Mail_Part $oMessage
 * @return string returns message content as utf-8 string from message object
 */
public static function contentDecoder ($oMessage, $bVerbose = false) {
    mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
    echo ($bVerbose)?("\tultimateContentDecode {\n"):('');      
    if($oMessage->headerExists('content-type')) {
        echo ($bVerbose)?("\t\t" . $oMessage->contentType . "\n"):('');
        preg_match('/^([a-z\/]+)(?:;\s+format=[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?(?:;\s+charset=([a-zA-Z0-9-]+))?/i', 
            str_replace('"', '', $oMessage->contentType), $matches);
        list(,$sMimeType,$sEncoding) = $matches;
        echo ($bVerbose)?("\t\tType of this part is {$sMimeType}, {$sEncoding}\n"):('');
    } else {
        $sContent = $oMessage->getContent();
        $sMimeType = 'text/plain';
        $sEncoding = mb_detect_encoding($sContent, self::$_sEncDetectOrder);
        echo ($bVerbose)?("\t\tUnknow content type. text/plain; charset={$sEncoding}\n"):('');
    }
    $sEncoding = strtoupper($sEncoding);
    if($oMessage->headerExists('content-transfer-encoding')) {
        $sQuoting = $oMessage->contentTransferEncoding;
        echo ($bVerbose)?("\t\tContent-Transfer-Encoding: " . $oMessage->contentTransferEncoding . "\n"):('');
    } else {
        $sQuoting = '';
    }
    $sContent = $oMessage->getContent();
    switch ($sQuoting) {
        case 'quoted-printable':
        case '7bit':
            $sContent = quoted_printable_decode($sContent);
            break;
        case 'base64':
            $sContent = base64_decode($sContent);
            break;
    }
    if ($sEncoding != 'UTF-8') {
        echo ($bVerbose)?("\t\tConvert encoding: {$sEncoding} -> UTF-8 \n"):('');
        $sContent = mb_convert_encoding($sContent, 'UTF-8', $sEncoding);
    }
    $sContent = trim(preg_replace(
            array('/^\s+/m', '/\s+$/m', '/[ \t]+/'),
            array('', '', ' '), $sContent));
    echo ($bVerbose)?("--\n{$sContent}\n--"):('');
    echo ($bVerbose)?("\t}\n"):('');
    return $sContent;
}
```